# Salesforce File Sync - How do I set Sync status in Apex?

Tags: apex, chatter-file, files

As above, I'd like to set the Sync status on new Files programmatically - does anyone know if it's possible and if so how?

[image: Files-info]

When new File records are created, they are set to un-synced mode, meaning they won't appear in the desktop client etc. I would like to set this programmatically via Apex.

I've had a look at the [`ContentDocument`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentdocument.htm) and [`ContentVersion`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentversion.htm) objects and I can't seem to find any field which controls this behaviour - am I missing something?

Comment: Bump, added a bounty. Anyone got any ideas on this one?

Comment: Is it implied by being in a particular ContentFolder or ContentWorkspace? One that aligns with the sync folder from your computer. I tried to test it, but couldn't be the sync app working. If just sits in the "Starting" status.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's not available in Apex or declaritive tools, but you can work with Salesforce Files Sync using the Chatter REST API.

> Salesforce Files Sync
>
> Chatter REST API for Salesforce Files Sync is generally available in
>   version 31.0. To use Chatter REST API to work with files and folders,
>   use these resources.
>
> **Move a file to a different folder**
>
> Move a file to a different folder using /chatter/files/fileId. These
>   request parameters for POST are no longer reserved for pilot:
>   isDataSync—The request is automatically generated by an automated
>   client.
>
> isInMyFileSync—true if the file is included in the user’s Salesforce
>   Files folder, and is synced between that folder and Chatter; false
>   otherwise.
>
> These request parameters for PATCH are no longer reserved for pilot:
>
> isInMyFileSync—true if the file is included in the user’s Salesforce
>   Files folder, and is synced between that folder and Chatter; false
>   otherwise. parentFolderId—ID of the containing folder.
>
> **Get information about folder, modify, or delete a folder** To get information about a folder, modify or delete a folder, use
>   /chatter/folders/folderId.
>
> **Get information about the contents of a folder and add items to a folder** To get information about the contents of a folder and add
>   items to a folder, use /chatter/folders/folderId/items.

And in particular for you:

> **Work with users files**
>
> isDataSync—The request is automatically generated by an automated
>   client.
>
> isInMyFileSync—true if the file is included in the user’s Salesforce
>   Files folder, and is synced between that folder and Chatter; false
>   otherwise.